# How to change "display name" for email contact in mac mail?

Tags: mail.app, email, contacts

Ive got an email contact with the email address careers@example.com , but for some reason in the "display name" for their email address in OSX mac mail, it shows up as "Studio - Example".

Here is what happens when i input the email address :

[image: screenshot of : Here is what happens when i input the email address]

If i right click the "display name, i can "edit address"

[image: screenshot of : If i right click the "display name, i can "edit address"]

Which will open the text edit options in the screenshot below, which works for this time, but next time i enter the email address again, i get the same issue.

Any ideas ?

[image: screenshot of Which will open the text edit options in the screenshot below, which works for this time, but next time i enter the email address again, i get the same issue.]

Comment: Have you added it to contacts and changed the display name there?

Comment: @SteveChambers , will give it a try and advise back

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the display name associated with that email address, as set by the email owner. You have no control over this unless/until you add it as a contact and override the display name. This is why when you get an email from a brand new address you typically see a display name instead of the raw email address.